# Insert new line in a backing bean string value

Tags: jsf-2

How to insert a new line between words for a backing bean value and display it on UI using JSF 2.0 framework? If we have address. The street name should be in first line and city and state should be in the second line. I am using a converter to add new line. But it does not show up on the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF is basically a HTML code generator. A new line is in HTML to be presented by the `<br />` tag, not by `\r\n` characters or something. You can just do it straight in the view instead of mingling view-specific details in the managed bean or a converter.

```
<h:outputText value="#{user.address.street} #{user.address.houseNumber}" />
<br />
<h:outputText value="#{user.address.city}, #{user.address.state}" />
```

Comment: Initially, I did the changes in the view. But there ui:fragments for each country and the code is huge. That's the reason I want to use a converter.

Comment: Well, whatever design approach you'd like to take, good or bad, you now at least know that you should be using `<br />` to represent a new line in HTML. If you populate it in the Java end, you only need to display it with `<h:outputText escape="false" />`. You should keep the potential XSS attack hole in mind when you want to redisplay user-controlled data in the same `<h:outputText>`.