# jsf managed bean method's string in html

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Hi i have this method in managed bean.

```
public String instructionsText() {
     String text = "Whether your web site needs a simple 'face lift' <br /> "+
                   " major 'reconstructive surgery,' the staff of"

    return text;
}
```

in my jsf page :

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aroche/delta/32/Help-icon.png" style="float:right" onclick="PF('dlgi').show();" alt="help" />
```

I want a line break in string text at the place of `<br />`.But i tried in different ways
(\n, \r\n, \r ,`<br>` , `<br />`).Nothing worked.Help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853790/insert-new-line-in-a-backing-bean-string-value

Comment: No .There are two <h:outputText> but i have only 1 and i want line braks to be displayed in html .

Comment: You need to escape html, as explained in the commments of that answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `escape` attribute for `h:outputText`, a Boolean flag which indicates whether to escape the HTML content or not.
By default the value is `true`. Set the value as `escape="false"`.
You can find the Doc Ref [HERE.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html)